# PHP Laravel - Returning view from a sub-directory

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to return a view from a sub-directory however when using the code below I get the error "Undefined variable: folder1"

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view("folder1/page1");
});
```

or

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view("/folder1/page1");
});
```

or

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view("folder1.page1");
});
```

The view "page1" is located in a folder called folder1, for example...

How do you return a view that's not located in the same directory?

Comment: the error got no thing to with you sub folder it has to do with  variable call `$products` in you `page1.blade.php` file

Comment: @ChamaraAbeysekara wait a minute. How did you know that?

Comment: just read the error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In laravel, by default views are stored in `resources/views` directory. Your view, page1.blade.php file is in `resources/views/folder1` directory. To return the view, we can use the global `view` helper as follows,

```
return view('folder1.page1');
```

For your case above, you can do this

```
Route::get('/',function(){
  return view('folder1.page1');
});
```

If you want to pass data into the view, there are many methods to do that,
you can use this

```
$data1= 'Sample data 1';
return view('folder1.page1',['data1'=>$data1]);
```

Or

```
$data1 = 'Sample data 1';
returnn view('folder1.page1')->with('data1',$data1);
```

Or

```
$data1 = 'Sample data 1';
return view('folder1.page1')->compact('data1');
```

Or

```
$data1 = 'Sample data 1';
return view('folder1.page1',compact('data1'));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try as below

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   return view("folder1.page1",compact('products'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the view itself, the problem is that you're not passing the `view` the `$product` variable it's using within the view to render data from a product / products.

Try something like this:

```
Router::get('/', function() {
  return view('folder1.page1', ['products' => App\Product::all()]);
}
```